# Detecting a tap on a UILabel using UITapGestureRecognizer not performing action

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Edit:
Thanks everyone, but this has gotten to be too general as it is clear there are deeper issues at hand. I'm going to try to delete this question. I appreciate all of your help!

We have a large UITableViewCell with a UILabel inside and we want to detect the user's single tap or touch on that label.  We're adding a UITapGestureRecognizer inside of our subclassed UITableViewCell:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 150, 20);
self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
self.titleLabel.text = self.title;
self.titleLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(expandButtonTapped:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.titleLabel addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

[cell.contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
```

We've also tried setting the target to the cell's UITableViewController, but same result, the action doesn't get performed.  When checking the debugger, the gesture is indeed there and attached to the label.

Edit:  After more investigating, if we add a normal UIButton to the cell, it cannot be clicked.  Doing more investigating, but here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (![self.metaDataSections count]) {
        return nil;
    }

    ACMTableCellMetaData *metaData = [self metaDataForIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:metaData.reuseIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [metaData createCell];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    cell = [metaData updateCellWithCellForReuse:cell];

    return cell;
}
```

The createCell method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)createCell
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super createCell];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:self.reuseIdentifier];

        cell.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(cell.contentView.frame),
                                CGRectGetMinY(cell.contentView.frame),
                                CGRectGetWidth(cell.contentView.frame),
                                ACM_TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT);
        [self setupExpandButtonInCell:cell];
    }        
    return cell;
}
```

updateCell method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)updateCellWithCellForReuse:(UITableViewCell *)cell {
    UILabel * titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:TITLE_TAG];

    titleLabel = self.titleLabel;
    self.cell = [super updateCellWithCellForReuse:cell];

    return self.cell;
}
```

I clipped out some code that I don't believe affects anything.  The didSelectRowAtIndexPath that is being over ridden in the the subclassed tableview doesn't have anything that would prevent user taps.  But strangely, if I put a break point there, it never gets hit when tapping the cells.  So I believe there are other issues at play here.  We can't see why this is the case however.

Comment: Make sure the userInteractionEnabled property on UILabel is set to YES, then you will be able to detect those actions.

Comment: @insane-36 Look at the 4th line of code in the question.

Comment: Then this should work. I set out an example and it is working fine. How does your CellForRowAtIndexPath look. If you could write that it could be more helpful.

Comment: Can you provide code of your createCell method?

Comment: You call other methods (`createCell`, `updateCell`) that could all be doing things the prevent the tap recognition. Show the code.

Comment: Is the first code snippet in your `layoutSubviews` of your cell class? And have you implemented anything in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that might be conflicting?

Comment: Side note- I had slightly related problems trying to get my cell elements to layout correctly in layoutSubviews, and creating as much as I could in storyboards helped clear up a lot of unexpected issues.

Comment: Thanks everyone, but this has gotten to be too general as it is clear there are deeper issues at hand.  I'm going to try to delete this question.  I appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this code in class, which inherits UITableViewCell, then instead of

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:self.titleLabel];
```

use

```
[self addSubView:self.titleLabel];
```

make sure to implement

```
-(void)expandButtonTapped:(parameter type)parameter{

}
```

in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention about

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell    =   [[TableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}
// Configure the cell...






    return cell;
}
```